# How can I evaluate php code in a string variable?

Tags: php, html

If I use the below code, I get the literal string `<b> DATE: <?php echo $date; ?> </b>` appended to content:

```
$content .= '<b> DATE: <?php echo $date; ?> </b>';
$pdf->writeHTML($content);
```

How can I instead get the value of `$date` there?

Answer (score 2):

You are trying to put php code inside a string which will not be evaluated again. Try this:

```php
$content .= '<b> DATE: ' . $date . '</b>';
$pdf->writeHTML($content);
```

Comment: I will call a mysql data as below. Please help me to use php on the string.```<svg style="margin-left:14px;margin-top:-3px;"id="<?php echo "barcode".$row["code"]; ?>"></svg>```

Comment: also relevant (and probably worth adding to the answer) https://stackoverflow.com/q/3446216/761202